# Vue loading all the chunks on the first request

Tags: vue.js, lazy-loading, router

I am learning Vue and just got to the routing chapter. I am able to create a template project with vue/cli with a initial router configuration. This is the Router code:

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home,
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ './views/About.vue'),
    },
  ],
});
```

According to the coments on the code and the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html#grouping-components-in-the-same-chunk) this should be enough to lazy load the About component.

When I try to load the app page the "about.js" script is fetched:

[image: About code not lazy loaded]

If I navigate to About the browser fetches the script from disk cache:

[image]

I got confused. I was expecting to see the script about.js loaded only after I navigate to the About page. Am I missing something?

Comment: maybe this [discussion](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/979) could answer your question..

Comment: @TJWeems Thanks! It was very useful. After disabling the prefetch plugin it worked as I expected.

Comment: awesome good to hear!

Comment: This solution is not worked for me. I am still getting all js file which must be loaded later as in your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [discussion](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/979) pointed by @TJWeems was very elucidative.

I obtained the expected behavior after disabling the prefetch plugin with webpack-chain. I just created a **vue.config.js** on my root dir (the same as package.json) with the following:

```
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: (config) => {
        config.plugins.delete('prefetch');
    }
};
```

Just to remember I did it for the sake of curiosity. I will probably leave the prefetch plugin enabled on future projects and just consider to disable it on specific situations.